# Generate an image with features ORB can detect

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

For the purposes of a unit test, I'm trying to create an image with features ORB can detect; this is preferable to storing a real-world image. I'm using simple geometric shapes with lots of corners, but ORB isn't finding anything -- why not?

This is my image:

[image: My image]

Which I generated with this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_dims = (480, 640)
center = (np.array(img_dims) / 2).astype(int)
radius = 10

features = np.zeros(img_dims+(3,), dtype=np.float32)

features = cv2.rectangle(features,
                         (center - radius)[::-1],
                         (center + radius)[::-1],
                         (0, 255, 0),
                         -1)
features = cv2.circle(features,
                      center[::-1],
                      radius,
                      (255, 0, 0),
                      2)
features = cv2.rectangle(features,
                         (center - int(radius / 2))[::-1],
                         (center + int(radius / 2))[::-1],
                         (0, 0, 255),
                         -1)

# cv2.imshow("", features)
# cv2.waitKey(-1)

detector = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=100000)
keypoints, descriptors = detector.detectAndCompute(features, None)
assert len(keypoints)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the datatype of the image, which needed to be `np.uint8`.